# How to display a list of employees joining on a particular date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c

I have a table `EMPLOYEE` and it contains data like this:

```
EID       JOB          JOINING_DATE
------    ----          -----------
1          SE         2015-01-01 00:00:00.0
2          SW         2015-01-02 00:00:00.0
3          SD         2015-01-03 00:00:00.0
4          SX         2015-01-04 00:00:00.0
5          SP         2015-01-05 00:00:00.0
6          SV         2015-01-06 00:00:00.0
7          SM         2015-01-07 00:00:00.0
8          SE         2015-01-04 00:00:00.0
9          SW         2015-01-03 00:00:00.0
10         SD         2015-01-01 00:00:00.0
11         SX         2015-01-03 00:00:00.0
12         SP         2015-01-03 00:00:00.0
13         SV         2015-01-02 00:00:00.0
8          SE         2015-01-04 00:00:00.0
9          SW         2015-01-03 00:00:00.0
10         SD         2015-01-01 00:00:00.0
11         SX         2015-01-03 00:00:00.0
12         SP         2015-01-03 00:00:00.0
13         SV         2015-01-02 00:00:00.0
```

I need to output like this:

```
EID     JOB    01-01-15   02-01-15    03-01-15
1        SE      1         0             0
2        SW      0         0             0
.
.
.
13       SV      0         2             0
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Please note below points.

1. You should not start column name with number.
2. In your input data, you have mentioned 7 distinct dates, but in your output you have mentioned only 3.
3. I am assuming that the eid and job are same for distinct employees, otherwise your logic would fail.

   ```
       with tbl1 as(
       select emp.*,
         case when joining_date = to_date('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') then 1 else 0 end as date_01_01_15,
         case when joining_date = to_date('2015-01-02','YYYY-MM-DD') then 1 else 0 end as date_02_01_15,
         case when joining_date = to_date('2015-01-03','YYYY-MM-DD') then 1 else 0 end as date_03_01_15
       from EMPLOYEE emp) 

       select tbl1.eid, tbl1.job,
           sum(date_01_01_15) as date_01_01_15,
           sum(date_02_01_15) as date_02_01_15,
           sum(date_03_01_15) as date_03_01_15 
       from tbl1
       group by tbl1.eid,tbl1.job
   ```

NOTE: I have taken the date format as YYYY-MM-DD. You can change as per your date format.
Also you can extend the case and sum statements to add other columns too.